# How to implement a weather API in cordova

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have to create an android weather app with cordova using data from openweathermap.

The thing is I install cordova and I get to the "hello world", but I have no idea how to get data from openweather.

I create the project in cordova, then I can edit that hello world  as it was a web page using html, and css.

But how do I make it to search for places and get data from openweathermap?

I have registered in openweathermap, got my own key, but don't know how to use it.
Don't even know what sohld I study to learn how to do it.

I think I should make a request to the openweather API, then openweather will reply with the weather data in json format, then I should get that data to my website/cordova app.

But how?

Thank you

Been looking for tutorials, but none I found explain what I want.
They use Ionic or react, stuff I don't know how to use.
I would like to keep it simple, just look for the city, and get the weather displayed, to know how it is done.

Comment: Please check the weather API on how to fetch data from it https://openweathermap.org/guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - You are going to be making GET requests to the server

Ok so, what you're looking for is the ability to fetch the weather data from the API server and display it on your component template somehow. What you need is the HTTPClientModule that comes with angular (and therefore with Ionic if you are using Angular as your frontend framework, v4 works with Vue and React as well).

I know this is rough for a lot of new developers so I'll make it as simple as possible for you, import the HTTPClientModule inside your app module so you can use it globally. Then, the best practice is to place all API calls(which is how you'll fetch the weather data with your key) inside a service. Create a GET request to the URI endpoint associated with the data you require and voila, you have your data.

From there, go to your page's typescript file and import the service and declare it in the class constructor. From there, you can make a function that subscribes (since Angular ships with RxJS) to the service function that fetches your data and saves it to a variable.

If you want to pass that onto your component view, well I'm sure you have interpolation figured out. Don't forget to use the async pipe since you are fetching asynchronous data.